# SQLite.swift swift 2 - select all columns of a table with * from in joined tables

Tags: swift2, sqlite.swift

I am trying to select all columns from a table in a joined SQLite.swift table statement with the help of the **select** function, but I always get the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'select' with an argument list of type '(Expression<Void>)'
```

Here is a demo code producing the error:

```
let messageId = Expression<String>("id")
let messageContent = Expression<String>("content")
let messageGroupId = Expression<String>("group_id")

let groupId = Expression<String>("id")
let groupName = Expression<String>("name")

if let db = try? Connection()
{
    let messageTable = Table("message")
    let groupTable = Table("group")


    try! db.run(messageTable.create() { t in
        t.column(messageId, primaryKey: true)
        t.column(messageContent)
        t.column(messageGroupId)
    })

    try! db.run(groupTable.create() { t in
        t.column(groupId, primaryKey: true)
        t.column(groupName)
    })


    let query = messageTable
        .join(groupTable, on: messageTable[messageGroupId] == groupTable[groupId])
        .filter(messageTable[messageGroupId] == "SOME GROUP ID")
        .select(messageTable[*])    // THIS SELECT IS CAUSING AN ERROR - WHAT IS WRONG?
}
```

The last call of the **select function** is always causing an error when I try to use the **STAR (all fields of a table)**. Is there any way I can use the star operator and not list all of the fields separately?

I am using Xcode 7.0.1, maybe this is fixed in 7.1 with swift 2.1?